# Find hidden elements in relation to focused element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, clone, hidden

I have a php page used for an Ajax call. It produces output in the form of a `<ul>` and `<li>` items. These items are being used as an auto-complete for an input field on the original page. The problem I am having is finding an elegant way to update other fields, some hidden, after the user clones them, based on the results of this Ajax call and subsequent sql query. Prefer to use jQuery, which I am sure is possible. I just can't find the easy solution. See all the next().next().next() I am currently using. Ugly!

First the php page:

```
<?PHP
include "dbconnect.php";

$partialSection=$_POST['partialSection'];
$school_id=$_POST['school_id'];


$sql="select course_section_code,course_name,course_credit_hours,school_id,ext_course_id from ext_courses 
 where course_section_code like '%$partialSection%' and school_id = $school_id";
$result = db_query($sql); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
        echo "<DIV>No external courses match your query for $partialSection at $school_id. Would you like to enter a new course? <button onclick='new_section()'>Yes</button></DIV>";
    }
    $output="<ul>";
    while ($record = get_record($result))
        {
            $section=$record['course_section_code'];
            $course_title=$record['course_name'];
            $credits=$record['course_credit_hours'];
            $school_id=$record['school_id'];
            $ext_course_id=$record['ext_course_id'];
            $output.="<li class=resultcss onmouseover='this.style.color=\"63b8ee\";this.style.backgroundColor=\"FFFFFF\"' onmouseout='this.style.color=\"FFFFFF\";this.style.backgroundColor=\"63b8ee\"' onclick='$(\".popup\").hide();$(\"*:focus\").val(\"".$section."\");$(\"*:focus\").next().next().next().val(\"".$course_title."\");$(\"*:focus\").next().next().next().next().next().val(\"".$credits."\");enter_data.ext_course_id0.value=\"".$ext_course_id."\"'>".$section."</li>";

        }
        $output.="</ul>";
    echo $output;
?>
```

Ok, now here is the HTML for the form:

```
<div class="cloneMe">
            <div>

                <label for="course_section0" class="">Section: <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="cinputs needsPopup" name="course_section[]" id="course_section0" size="8" onfocus="check_contents();" ONKEYUP="get_section(this.value,$('#school_id').val());" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" class="" name="ext_course_id[]" id="ext_course_id0">
                <label for="course_name0" class="">Name: <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="cinputs" name="course_name[]" id="course_name0" size="30">&nbsp;
                <label for="course_credits0" class="">Credits: <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="cinputs" name="course_credits[]" id="course_credits0" size="3">&nbsp;
                <label for="course_grade0" class="">Grade: <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <select class="cinputs" name="course_grade[]" id="course_grade0">
                    <option>Grade:</option>
                    <option>A</option>
                    <option>A-</option>
                    <option>B+</option>
                    <option>B</option>
                    <option>B-</option>
                    <option>C+</option>
                    <option>C</option>
                    <option>C-</option>
                    <option>D+</option>
                    <option>D</option>
                    <option>D-</option>
                    <option>F</option>
                    <option>P</option>
                    <option>CR</option>
                    <option>NC</option>
                    <option>IP</option>
                    <option>I</option>

                </select>&nbsp;
                <label for="hours_awarded0" class="">Hours Awarded: <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="cinputs" name="hours_awarded[]" id="hours_awarded0" size="3">&nbsp;
                <label for="baker_equiv0" class="">Baker Equivalent: <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>     
                <input type="text" class="cinputs needsPopup" name="baker_equiv[]" id="baker_equiv0" size="8" ONKEYUP="get_equiv(this.value);">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" class="" name="baker_equiv_id[]" id="baker_equiv_id0">
                 <label for="quest0" class="">Quest: <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="cinputs" name="quest[]" id="quest0" size="3">&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="clone">Add Course</button>
                    <button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button> 
            </div>
```

Link shows the cloned forms in red brackets.

http://www.rp-software.com/Screenshot.JPG

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Note: though I [answererd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12484612/520779) your question, these kinds of questions are generally [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) in stackoverflow. Ask them at [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. I'm voting to close, and suggesting moderators to migrate this question to that site.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure what the difference is though. Maybe you can explain...

Comment: Well, this is just my opinion, but from what I understood you have a fully working code (i.e. no actual problem to be solved) and are looking for ways to improve it. That's what codereview is for. But I might be mistaken, if you're actually asking a specific question then it's really on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, instead of outputting every style and behavior for each `li`, consider moving them to a separate css and javascript files. Your `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` for instance could be replaced by hover rules:

```
.resultcss {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#63b8ee;
}

.resultcss:hover {
    color:#63b8ee;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

For the values your php script is inserting in the `li`, you could use HTML5 `data` attributes. If you clone it, the data will be preserved:

```
$output.="<li class='resultcss' data-section='".$section."' data-title='".$course_title."' data-credits='".$credits."' data-id='".$ext_course_id."'>".$section."</li>";
```

For the `onclick` callback, use jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, that works for both current and future elements as well (including cloned ones):

```
$('body').on('click', '.resultcss', function(e) {
    var data = $(this).data();
    $(".popup").hide();
    $("*:focus").val(data.section)
        .next().next().next().val(data.title)
        .next().next().val(data.credits);
    enter_data.ext_course_id0.value = data.id;
});
```

Note that I still used `next`. If you really want to avoid it, you can use additional classes in your html:

```
<input type="text" class="cinputs course_title" name="course_name[]" id="course_name0" size="30">&nbsp;
<input type="text" class="cinputs course_credits" name="course_credits[]" id="course_credits0" size="3">&nbsp;
```

Then refer to it using `find` or `children` (using `end` to return to the previous context):

```
    $("*:focus").val(data.section)
        .find('.course_title').val(data.title).end()
        .find('.couse_credits').val(data.credits);
```

Comment: Great suggestions, mgibsonbr! Some of which I had already planned on implementing, but some, especially using multiple classes never dawned on me. That should remove the pain of having to find and count all the elements to know the number of next()s I need. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more thing: I noticed your `cloneMe` sub-elements have ids. When you clone an element, it should either: a) not have an id; b) change the id of the cloned element. You might know that already, but it's good to point out nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. I do change the id of the cloned elements. I wasn't sure how else to reach them and update them if I didn't.